# how to select Multiselectitem elements in code behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am attempting to preselect certain items in a multiselectlist when the Multiselectlist page is navigated to, since my selected items to not remain selected once the page is navigated from. I have created a list that holds the selected values to be used (named StrobeBrushList located in a custom class named Settings.cs that uses isolated storage to save the values, and works correctly), but I am unsure of how to properly re-select those items when the page is navigated from and then back to.

*Note, ColorItem and ColorHelper are also custom classes used to get the colors and values

Multiselectlist.xaml

```
<toolkit:MultiselectList x:Name="ColorList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tap="ColorList_Tap">
                <toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <!--<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Brush}" Width="50" Height="50"/>-->
                            <CheckBox Background="{Binding Brush}"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12,10,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:MultiselectList>
```

Multiselectlist.xaml.cs

```
List<ColorItem> solidColorBrushList;

public MultiselectlistPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        solidColorBrushList = new List<ColorItem>()
        {
            new ColorItem { Brush = ColorHelper.ToSolidColorBrush("#FFF0F8FF"), Name = "alice blue" },
            new ColorItem { Brush = ColorHelper.ToSolidColorBrush("#FFFAEBD7"), Name = "antique white" },
            new ColorItem { Brush = ColorHelper.ToSolidColorBrush("#FF00FFFF"), Name = "aqua" },
            new ColorItem { Brush = ColorHelper.ToSolidColorBrush("#FF7FFFD4"), Name = "aquamarine" },
            new ColorItem { Brush = ColorHelper.ToSolidColorBrush("#FFF0FFFF"), Name = "azure" },  //dont translate!?
            new ColorItem { Brush = ColorHelper.ToSolidColorBrush("#FFF5F5DC"), Name = "beige" },

                   ...

        };

        this.ColorList.ItemsSource = solidColorBrushList;

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ColorListPage_Loaded);
    }

    void ColorListPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //show checkboxes when page is loaded
        this.ColorList.IsSelectionEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (solidColorBrushList == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ItemContainerGenerator itemContainerGenerator = this.ColorList.ItemContainerGenerator;

        //Settings.StrobeBrushList.Value contains the list of brush items selected by the user
        foreach (SolidColorBrush scB in Settings.StrobeBrushList.Value)
        {
            //this.SetCheckBoxesSelected(true, null);
            if (scB != null)
            {                    
                foreach(ColorItem cI in solidColorBrushList)
                { 
                    //compare the color values of the lists and only select (and show checkmark?) of items in the saved list
                    if (cI.Brush.Color == scB.Color)
                    {
                        DependencyObject vI = itemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cI);
                        MultiselectItem msI = vI as MultiselectItem;
                        if (msI != null)
                        {
                            msI.IsSelected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you still having issues with selecting items?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of items that the multiselectlist is bound to, you can simply add the "selected items" to the list's `SelectedItems` collection before adding it to the bound list.

With some xaml like this

```
<toolkit:MultiselectList ItemsSource="{Binding AllColors}">
```

and in your populate code

```
MultiselectList list = /* The list from your xaml */;
foreach (ColorModel model in allModels) {
    ColorViewModel viewModel = new ColorViewModel(model);
    if (shouldBeSelected(model)) {
        list.SelectedItems.Add(viewModel);
    }
    AllColors.Add(viewModel);
}
```